# Macbook 'Missing Space' Issue after Removing Partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, fusion-drive

I had previously set up my 2012 Macbook Pro in a fusion drive configuration (250GB ssd and 500GB HD) for macOS and had a 250ish GB partition for Windows on my 500 GB hard drive. I tried removing the partition using disk utility but seem to have gotten into a bit of a mess as I can no longer see the previously partitioned space in disk utility and my macOS partition has not resized to make use of the full 750 GB which shoud now be available to it. I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue and enabling my macOS partition to use the full storage available to it (whilst preferably keeping the fusion drive configuration).

I have run `diskutil list` from Terminal in recovery mode to obtain the following:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         298.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         249.8 GB   disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS macOS Base System       2.0 GB     disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +548.7 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Stores disk1s2, disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Fusion Drive            513.8 GB   disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.6 MB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                507.0 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk3s4

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk20

/dev/disk21 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk21

/dev/disk22 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk22

-bash-3.2#
```

Comment: Welcome to Apple.SE! I don't really know a lot about such issues, but some of the recent ones were marked as duplicates or were redirected to other useful and detailed answers on the site itself. It is always a good idea to search for similar questions. Use [tag] to narrow down search. Also, [Klanomath's answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:93229+[partition]) and  [David's answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:107222+[partition]) are always helpful :)

Comment: Can I assume you have already tried the command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`? If this did not work, then post the output from the command `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size`.

Comment: Thanks for the info @ankiiiiiii, my partition structure looked a bit different to the others I saw so I didn't want to mess anything up

Comment: @DavidAnderson Cheers, have just tried the first command and got an error:

Comment: ```APFS Container Resize error code is 49174
A problem occurred; undoing all changes
Modifying partition map
Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures```

Comment: I get this from your second command string @DavidAnderson:  ```-bash-3.2# diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size
   Partition Offset:          209735680 Bytes (409640 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 298.9 GB (298898665472 Bytes) (exactly 583786456 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes```

Comment: The one with my MacOS partition is the one called "Fusion Drive" (if that helps)